# How to display date fields that are before the current time - Access

Tags: microsoft-access

I am creating a database for a school project and am trying to create a query for the 'clients' that have had their appointment completed already.

I have a field with the date inside and would like to know how I would create a query to show the 'clients' that have appointment dates assigned to them that have already passed the current date.

[image]

Here is a picture of the query that I have gotten so far, I don't know if it will be useful, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Appointment_Date` is a true date field (not a text field), then you can select all records for which the `Appointment_Date` has already elapsed by specifying the following in the criteria for the `Appointment_Date` field:

```
< Date()
```